# Too much RAM is being used even if the system is moderately ideal in Ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, ram

We are using Ubuntu 20.4

System Configurations: 240GB SSD, 8 GB RAM, Intel® Core™ i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4

we are using a few software like Google Chrome, Vs code and Notepad ++. We have noticed that the system is using too much RAM even if we are not using that many apps. Like for ex. there's only Google Chrome and File manager is opened and they are not even being used. they are in the ideal state still we see that 6.8 GB approx. 87% of RAM is being used. How can that be possible? We tried to increase the RAM to 16 GB but still, the system is using 12GB RAM even in an ideal state.

One more thing, we are using Magento in Ubuntu and have set up 2 Magento websites in the localhost. we have noticed that when we run the upgrade, deploy commands 2-3 times it is wearing down the system too much and the system is getting stuck to the extent where we have to forcefully restart the PC but as I said even if we increase the RAM to 16GB still the system is occupying 12GB then how can other software or services be able to use the remaining memory? that will obviously wear down the system.

Can someone help us with this issue?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.4 might it be 20.04? How have you noticed the system is using too much RAM ? What does this mean wearing down the system too much? No one can help till the vague statements have some more info.

Comment: @David Sorry my bad. it is indeed Ubuntu 20.04. we are seeing in the System monitor. I mean that 87% of RAM is being used even if only 1-2 apps are being used in the system. So when we try to use more apps then it is using almost all of the RAM and because of that the system is being stuck very often

Comment: RAM is made to be used. Unused RAM is wasted RAM. In particular you are running applications that take use of available RAM. The software you mentioned will gobble up RAM when it's available and will release it for other apps as necessary. Chrome, especially, loves to use RAM.  8 GB is not a ton of RAM these days and 12GB/16GB is a non-issue. Are you sure that there's actually a problem here?

Comment: Are you sure your problems have anything to do with RAM? You should keep a resource monitor running and if the system hangs at 80% RAM usage then the problem probably isn't RAM being used it's something else.  Does the problem only occur when you use one particular application?

Comment: No, I also didn't think that the problem lies only with the RAM. It usually happens when I run the upgrade/deploy command 2-3 times in the terminal for our Magento setup and recently we are noticing that when we work in VS code the VS code also keeps getting stuck. At this point, even I am not sure about the exact cause of this issue. Do you think that I should increase the RAM.

Comment: Top is a handy tool, use it from the command line and you might pinpoint the memory hog.